# merging two external edge by python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a project that I should merge 2 images of the cross-section of an Object. most of the time because of different perspectives and some Noises the two images don't merge exactly. at some points, it becomes two lines whereas it should be one. so I want to make it one line by some approaches like meaning, interpolating, etc. but I don't know how can I do that. I'm working on Opencv. Note that I also have images of each of the cross-sections in different images in the position that they are in the merged image. the thickness of each line is one

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code of how you generated the above edges?

Comment: I would do 1.Registration before moving to BW images of edges, so that the lines do sit on top of each other. 2. read how Canny edge detector works, it solves very similar problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't come up with an optimal solution, but if you detect the lines and play with coordinates you may reach similar:

[image]

The shape is not ideal, but it should give you an intuition about where to start.

I user `createFastLineDetector` to find the lines and then draw the second image into the first image.

I used the default parameters from the [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/ded/group__ximgproc__fast__line__detector.html#gaa9636e5033cd2939ec50810f2b2bd853) :

```py
_length_threshold = 10
_distance_threshold = 1.41421356
_canny_th1 = 50
_canny_th2 = 50
_canny_aperture_size = 3
_do_merge = False
```

Maybe you can enhance the image by changing the above parameters.

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

edge1 = cv2.imread('edge1.png')
edge2 = cv2.imread('edge2.png')

gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(edge1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(edge2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

d = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector(_do_merge=True)

lines1 = d.detect(gray1)
lines2 = d.detect(gray2)

for current_line1 in lines1:
    (x11, y11, x12, y12) = current_line1[0]
    cv2.line(edge1, (x11, int(y11 - 5)), (x12, int(y12 - 5)), (255, 255, 255), 3)

for current_line2 in lines2:
    (x11, y11, x12, y12) = current_line2[0]
    cv2.line(edge1, (x11, int(y11 - 15)), (x12, int(y12 - 15)), (255, 255, 255), 3)
```